# I am trying to displaying today date -1year in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my program I am trying to display today's date minus 1 year example today date(29-4-2016) i want result (29-4-2015). I've tried following code please help me any one.

```
<div id="date-picker" class="input-group date">
   <input class="mdl-textfield__input cDate" name="fromDate" type="text" disabled="disabled" placeholder=" dd/mm/yyyy" />
</div>
<script>     
    $("#date-picker").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", "0");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() - 1);
$("#date-picker input").datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
}).datepicker("setDate", d);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="date-picker" class="input-group date">
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input cDate" name="fromDate" type="text"  placeholder=" dd/mm/yyyy" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Just Follow the JS code as per your needs

```
<script>
     function convertDate(inputFormat) 
     {
         function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
         var d = new Date(inputFormat);
         return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
     } // This is a Fuction For Convert Your Date into dd/mm/yyyy Format

     var today = new Date();    // Eg. Wed Apr 29 2016 17:07:18 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
     var a = convertDate(today); // It Will Convert Your Date By calling Above Function
     alert(a);  // 02/05/2016
     var pastDate = today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - 1);
     var b = convertDate(pastDate);
     alert(b);      // 02/05/2015
     $("#date-picker input").datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'}).datepicker("setDate", pastDate);    //Set newDate in your DatePicker what ever you want .
</script>
```

Here is some Extra Date-Time related function which you can use (Using (-/+) As per Past and Future timing needs)

```
**Method**             **Description**
getDate()          Returns the day of the month (from 1-31)
getDay()           Returns the day of the week (from 0-6)
getFullYear()      Returns the year (four digits)
getHours()         Returns the hour (from 0-23)
getMilliseconds()  Returns the milliseconds (from 0-999)
getMinutes()       Returns the minutes (from 0-59)
getMonth()         Returns the month (from 0-11)
getSeconds()       Returns the seconds (from 0-59)
```

You Can also Refer Mozila developer Network [Date - JavaScript _ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate)

And W3Schools [JavaScript Dates](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) for More Information

Comment: i followed those step's still not coming date format "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: @ramesh bogandla Check latest Updated Answer use the function for check dd/mm/yyyy formated dates.(You can use your desire delimiters [- , . , etc] Just replace it in join()) and than set your date picker with your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate), which accepts "date periods", eg relative date strings, such as `"-1y"` Example:

```
$("#testDateField").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
}).datepicker("setDate", "-1y");
```

Example Fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/mv834L85/1/